# Footer menu only shows up on home page

Tags: php, html, css, footer

I added a menu to the footer of my site in functions/footer.php, and it shows up as desired on my home page, but it doesnt show up on any of the Post pages.

here is the website http://www.cultcitychi.com/

Below is my footer.php code

`?>

```
</div><!-- #content -->

<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
    <div class="site-info">

<?php // footer menu
wp_nav_menu( array('container_class' => 'menu-footer',
'theme_location' => 'secondary' ) ); ?>

    </div><!-- .site-info -->
</footer><!-- #colophon -->
```

`

Comment: Did you include your footer in the template **single.php**?

Comment: single.php already ended with that code

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code at the bottom of your `single.php` file in order to display the footer on each post page:

```
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**UPDATE:**

I checked your website using the developer tools and the footer is present on the posts page but it's not appearing because of a flaw in your CSS. Please add the following CSS at the bottom of your stylesheet and that should solve the problem:

```
.single.single-thumbnail .site {
     height: auto;
}

.single.single-thumbnail .site-footer {
     padding-top: 0px;
}

.site-info {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

footer#colophon {
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: that code was already there.  the menu shows up on other Pages, the problem is that it doesnt show up on Posts.

Comment: can you share the link to your website?

Comment: @pascale Please check the edit which I've made to my answer above, that should solve the problem which you're facing.

Comment: check out the 2nd post, for example: your addition (which did work) added a new footer container that shifts the page up, and off the top of the page in the example of the 2nd post.

Comment: Add this CSS to your stylesheet along with the CSS from my edited answer above: `.single.single-thumbnail .entry-background { height: 667px; top: 0px; margin-top: -64px; }`. This should work perfectly.

Comment: this looks much better!  there is still a minor shift up in the page, though--anything else we can do?  could we somehow add the menu to the same container that houses the "previous" and "next" post buttons?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't really make much difference plus the styling of the Previous/Next buttons got messed up as well.

Comment: no worries--your input is much appreciate Fahad.  Thank you